# Is there a way to have a Text element of a Card generated by the elements of a Firebase collection change for each card consecutively?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I need this Text component to have a number for each Card, numbering them consecutively (1,2,3,4...) so that each time I add more elements, follow the sequence.

[image]

As seen in the image, the number prints on all the Cards, and I want them to have different numbering and consecutively.

[image]

Firebase elements are displayed correctly in the app.

[image]

I tried to add a for the function to the text field to obtain the number of elements of my list but when printing the elements I did not have a readable result. I hope to make myself understand I don't have that much experience.

**Location of components**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tptxp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vupiu.png)

Comment: what you use for column list? LazyColumn?

Comment: I use LazyColumns but in the file where the Cards are structured no, I have another file where LazyColumn is but there I only call the function, above update information on the location of the components so that it is better distinguished

Comment: By the way, it's a nice question regarding Firestore and Jetpack Compose. I like it ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to have a Text element of a Card generated by the elements of a Firebase collection change for each card consecutively?

For sure there is. You can use the [itemsIndexed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListScope).itemsIndexed(kotlin.collections.List,kotlin.Function2,kotlin.Function2,kotlin.Function3)) extension function which provides the number that you're looking for:

```
LazyColumn() {
    itemsIndexed(yourList) { index, item ->
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 20.dp),
            text = (index + 1).toString(),
            //...
        )
    }
}
```

I have added `index + 1` so that the numbering starts from 1 and not from 0.

Comment: thanks for your answer but because my Text component is in another File and that function is called to another File where my LazyColumn is, it does not allow me to use the itemsIndexed() property, above I have added information on the structure of the File

Comment: I see, in that case, you should change the `items` inside `ListWord` into `itemsIndexed` and pass the index to the `ListItem` as an argument. So you should have `ListItems(word, onItemClick, index)`. Give it a try and tell me if it works.